# Ruby check if record exist in mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Just simple check with ruby driver if record exist in database.

Like

```
Main = db.collection(main)
Record = main.find("record" => name)
If record?
 Puts record exist
Else
 Dont exist
End
```

This doesnt work can someone tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The following will put true or false whether the record exists

```
puts main.record.where(record: name).exists?
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with the collection method "find" as you did, but the selector must be a hash.

```
  col = db.collection(main)
  record = col.find({:property => value})
```

Find also accepts an optional hash of options.
Take a look at the documentation. http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method